# Launch / Check application

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following script which I am using in an intranet environment:

```
function LaunchApp(the_app) {
    var ws = new ActiveXObject("WScript.Shell");
    ws.Exec(the_app);
}
```

This allows me to pass it an exe path to launch directly from a web page as long as internet explorer's intranet security settings are adjusted.

The problem is, that not everyone in out network has the same applications, some has more, others have less.  So I was wondering, is it possible to extend the script above to some how check if the path given exists on the users computer before attempting to launch it?

Comment: Oh goody, an IE Only shop! :)

Comment: Is this type of stuff possible in chomium and firefox?

Comment: Not without writing a browser plugin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a [`FileSystemObject`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6kxy1a51%28VS.85%29.aspx) and interact with the client's filesystem.